# How do I configure Elmah with .NET Core to log to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, elmah

I've installed the package "ElmahCore" which allowed me to use Elmah in .NET Core. It's set up by:

`services.AddElmah();`

in the startup.cs

I want to change it to log to SQL so it's persistent. However it's unclear how - there is no web.config, it appears to be no-configuration. There aren't any options I can see either to add SQL logging.

There's an `elmah.corelibrary nuget package`, but it doesn't seem to play with the first library - doing `services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>` which has been suggested elsewehre doesn't work because it's the wrong `ErrorLog` class.

Alternatively if there's a better framework for .net core that will log exceptions with persistence and allow sending notification e-mails it would be appreciated, I am wondering if Elmah is past its sell by date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `elmah.corelibrary` package is part of ELMAH for ASP.NET (not core). To log to SQL Server from ASP.NET Core, you need to install the `ElmahCore.Sql` NuGet package to get the correct `SqlErrorLog` class:

```cs
using ElmahCore.Mvc;
using ElmahCore.Sql;

...

services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=ELMAH;Integrated Security=True;";
});
```

As for your questions for ELMAH in general, it is definitely not dead. ELMAH for ASP.NET is sort of complete while work on different log "appenders" still happen. ElmahCore is a port from the original ELMAH code to support ASP.NET Core. I'm the founder of [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/) which offer you to store error messages in the cloud (as well as a range of other features which makes the name confusing I know). There are similar solutions out there like [Raygun](https://raygun.com) and [Stackify](https://stackify.com/).