# How to get Elmah working with .Net 6 F# Web Api Project

Tags: f#, elmah

I've used Elmah before in a C# project years ago and I have recently started using F# and having a bit of trouble.  I have a .Net 6 Web Api project

from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457531/how-do-i-configure-elmah-with-net-core-to-log-to-sql) I see the key code is:

```
services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=ELMAH;Integrated Security=True;";
});
```

I am a bit lost as to how to actually get this working in my F# program.fs

It currently looks like this:

```
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =

    let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)
    builder.Services.AddControllers()

    let app = builder.Build()
    app.UseHttpsRedirection()

    app.UseAuthorization()
    app.MapControllers()
    app.Run()

    exitCode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in F#, and with asp.net minimal API that you are using, would be to put this before `let app = ...`:

```ml
builder.Services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(fun options ->
    options.ConnectionString <- "Server=localhost;Database=ELMAH;Integrated Security=True;"
)
```